# Kibana showing error

Tags: linux, kibana

I've installed kibana on linux. i've assign 5601 port as external host(log.gurukul.ninja). but when i run ./bin/kibana command in linux putty terminal i got this error.

```
 log   [03:03:35.042] [warning][plugins-discovery] Expect plugin "id" in camelCase, but found: beats_management
  log   [03:03:35.053] [warning][plugins-discovery] Expect plugin "id" in camelCase, but found: triggers_actions_ui
  log   [03:03:42.629] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "visTypeXy" is disabled.
  log   [03:03:42.630] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "auditTrail" is disabled.
  log   [03:03:42.871] [warning][config][deprecation] Config key [monitoring.cluster_alerts.email_notifications.email_address] will be required for email notifications to work in 8.0."
  log   [03:03:43.044] [fatal][root] { Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 175.101.13.126:5601
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1263:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen (net.js:1461:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:61:10)
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '175.101.13.126',
  port: 5601 }
```

Thank you !

Comment: Are you sure the IP is correct? Is there something else already running on port 5601?

Comment: yeah i'm sure that IP.

Comment: it's fixed.it's server configuration issue.